# INSERT INTO ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE IN POSTGRES to handle values that are no longer present in the source table

Tags: postgresql

I have an insert statement as follows:

```
insert into target (hostname,shared_owners,shared_owners_emails)
select distinct hostname,shared_owners,shared_owners_emails
from source
where shared_owners is not null and shared_owners_emails is not null
on conflict (hostname)
do update set
shared_owners = excluded.shared_owners,
shared_owners_emails = excluded.shared_owners_emails,
demise_status= case when excluded.hostname is null then true else false end;
```

My question here is, I want to mark the column demise_status to TRUE when the source table no longer matches on the key (`hostname`), else if they still match then FALSE. I'm unsure if my `case` clause is entirely correct in this case, since it comes after `do update on conflict`, I believe it will never catch the `true` case correct ?
How can I handle this situation ?

Comment: Could you please share the ddl for the table involved? Can hostname be null and violate a unique constraint?

Comment: Hostname is a primary key on the target table

Comment: A primary key can never be null

Comment: right, so that's why i am looking for a different solution to this problem.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "*when the source table no longer matches on the key*". Either there is a conflict on the key (in which case the `UPDATE` runs) or there isn't (in which case the new row is inserted and no `UPDATE` occurs). So what does "no longer" refer to?

Answer (score 1):

In your current query, the value of the `demise_status` column is set to true if the value of the `hostname` column in the excluded row is null, and to false otherwise. The `SELECT` statement only returns rows where the `hostname` column is not null (which is not possible for the value of the `hostname` column in the excluded row to be null since it's a primary key in `target`), meaning that the value of the `demise_status` column will always be set to false.

Taking a shot in the dark, you could set the value of the `demise_status` column to true for rows in the target table that do not have a matching row in the source table based on the hostname column. (this is under the assumption that `source.hostname` can be nullable).

Assuming this the DDL for the tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE target (
    hostname TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    shared_owners TEXT,
    shared_owners_emails TEXT,
    demise_status BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE source (
    hostname TEXT REFERENCES target(hostname),
    shared_owners TEXT,
    shared_owners_emails TEXT,
    demise_status BOOLEAN
);
```

I think if you use an outer join between the `target` and `source` tables to find rows in the `target` table that do not have a matching row in the `source` table, and then update those rows to set the value of the `demise_status` column to true.

```sql
UPDATE target
SET demise_status = true
FROM target as T
LEFT JOIN source as S ON T.hostname = S.hostname
WHERE S.hostname IS NULL;
```